# How to shape ndarray to be indexable by ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

diving into machine learning and python and can't figure out how to shape my q_table.

I made a simple tic-tac-toe game with a 3 by 3 board. I realized for simplicity it's probably smarter to use a flat array of size 9 to represent the board.
Now for my q_table i want it to be indexable by the board state which is a flat array of size 9.

So let's say board looks like this (everything empty except the center cell has an 0):

```
>>> board = [-1,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1]
```

Now i want access my q_table like so and get another array of size 9 with the actions:

```
>>> q_table[board]   
array([-0.2,-0.3,-0.1,-0.5,0,-0.7,-0.2,-0.4,0.9])
```

So when initializing the q_table, is there a way to make the index an array of size 9?

```
>>> q_table = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=0, size=([9],[9]))
```

Having a hard time with tuples, lists, arrays in python.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: out of curiosity, I guess with the way you have attempted, you would require a huge matrix. It would require `2^9` rows (or columns depending on how you see it)

Comment: Have you tried `np.arange(9) >>> array([0,1,2,...7,8])`?

Comment: @learner yeah i guess that's true it'd even be `3^9` because the possible states are -1, 0 and 1.

Comment: though I can't answer the way you have asked for it, a way to do this would be add 1 to the `board` list and then take the dot product of `board` and an array containing `(0, 1, .., 9)`. The number you get after doing this would be the column (row) you'd be looking for